# IntelliJ IDEA - could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugins

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, kotlin, corda

Trying to open a Corda demo in IntelliJ IDEA and getting this error when it tries to import gradle settings

> Error:Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugins:1.1.4.
>   Searched in the following locations:
>       file:/C:/Users/Default/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugins/1.1.4/kotlin-gradle-plugins-1.1.4.pom
>       file:/C:/Users/Default/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugins/1.1.4/kotlin-gradle-plugins-1.1.4.jar
>       https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugins/1.1.4/kotlin-gradle-plugins-1.1.4.pom
>       https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugins/1.1.4/kotlin-gradle-plugins-1.1.4.jar
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugins/1.1.4/kotlin-gradle-plugins-1.1.4.pom
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugins/1.1.4/kotlin-gradle-plugins-1.1.4.jar
>   Required by:
>       project :

I can't find any documentation to suggest how to fix this, Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There seems to be a typo in the build script: the correct name of the artifact is `kotlin-gradle-plugin` (without `s`).

Check the dependency declaration in your `build.gradle`:

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:..."
```

It's described in the docs here: [Using Gradle](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#plugin-and-versions)

Comment: Eyyyy, this guy!

Comment: What does the documentation say is the correct name for the artifact?  plugin or plugins?  (What I mean to say, is, bonus points for, and please do, add link.)

Comment: It's `kotlin-gradle-plugin`, see [(link)](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#plugin-and-versions), updated the answer as well.