# Could not find kotlin-gradle-plugin for Kotlin script Gradle

Tags: kotlin, uberjar, gradle-kotlin-dsl, shadowjar

build fails, classpath error:

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/kotlinShadowJar$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/kotlinShadowJar$ gradle clean

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'kotlinShadowJar'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/home/thufir/.gradle/caches/4.3.1/embedded-kotlin-repo-1.1.51-1/repo/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin//kotlin-gradle-plugin-.pom
         file:/home/thufir/.gradle/caches/4.3.1/embedded-kotlin-repo-1.1.51-1/repo/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin//kotlin-gradle-plugin-.jar
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin//kotlin-gradle-plugin-.pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin//kotlin-gradle-plugin-.jar
         https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/repo/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin//kotlin-gradle-plugin-.pom
         https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/repo/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin//kotlin-gradle-plugin-.jar
     Required by:
         project :

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

`cat build.gradle.kts`:

```
import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        gradleScriptKotlin()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath(kotlinModule("gradle-plugin"))
        classpath("com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:1.2.3")
    }
}

apply {
    plugin("kotlin")
    plugin("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow")
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

val shadowJar: ShadowJar by tasks
shadowJar.apply {
    manifest.attributes.apply {
        put("Implementation-Title", "Gradle Jar File Example")
        put("Implementation-Version" version)
        put("Main-Class", "com.mkyong.DateUtils")
    }

    baseName = project.name + "-all"
}
```

The buildfile was a [direct copy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41795221/262852) of a working build.  The context is getting started with [Kotlin script Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48661330/262852).  So far as I can tell the script [should be good](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35651561/262852).

Note that I'm *not* using intelli-J, this is strictly from the CLI with Kotlin script Gradle.

perhaps it's something quite [simple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47330169/262852), like "plugin" versus "plugins"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the error logs, you can see the plugin version request:

```
Searched in the following locations:
     file:/home/thufir/.gradle/caches/4.3.1/embedded-kotlin-repo-1.1.51-1/repo/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin//kotlin-gradle-plugin-.pom
     file:/home/thufir/.gradle/caches/4.3.1/embedded-kotlin-repo-1.1.51-1/repo/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin//kotlin-gradle-plugin-.jar
     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin//kotlin-gradle-plugin-.pom
     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin//kotlin-gradle-plugin-.jar
     https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/repo/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin//kotlin-gradle-plugin-.pom
     https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/repo/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin//kotlin-gradle-plugin-.jar
```

You can see that a version is not requested on each plugin request because they are looking for `kotlin-gradle-plugin-.jar`.

If you [look at the source](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/blob/6a3c51a65e8423aa33432b816996360cd32e7906/buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/codegen/GenerateKotlinDependencyExtensions.kt#L92-L94), you will also see that `kotlinModule` is deprecated.

I would recommend a few different changes to improve the build script:

1. Using the Gradle wrapper (`./gradlew`
2. Specify a version for your `kotlinModule` until you upgrade your Gradle version - `kotlinModule("gradle-plugin", "1.1.51")`
3. Use the `plugins {}` block instead of `buildscript` for plugins